# how to use the css grid

Tags: html, css

I'm a noob web developer trying to develop my first website. I'm having trouble understanding the css grid system. In my code, I've got a container div that is where I define the grid in my css, and where I define the grid in css i think I'm making four columns, So aren't my child divs supposed to be placed next to each other? one's sitting on top of the other and I don't know how to fix it. Here's what I wrote:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border-style: dotted;
}

#app {
  border-style: dotted;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.otherStuff {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="app">
    <h1> hello</h1>
    <p>world</p>
  </div>
  <div class="otherStuff">
    <h1> otherStuff </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've removed the JavaScript tag because the *standard* CSS grid does not have anything to do with such language. If you're in fact referring to some third-party framework or JavaScript library please edit the question.

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` creates 3 columns, not 4. If you add one more `1fr` then it will be 4 columns.

Comment: From what I can see, the code you gave is working as expected . The divs are right next to each other. So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Indeed, you are creating only 3 columns here. And your grid has only 2 children. If you want to better see what's going on, you can use the Firefox quantum dev tools which will clearly let you inspect your grid.